# What is the term for this family of improper integrals?

Tags: integration, terminology, improper-integrals

What is the name of the integrals of this form?

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{x}{1}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\cdots\sin\left(\frac{x}{2n + 1}\right)}{\left(\frac{x}{1}\right)\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\cdots\left(\frac{x}{2n + 1}\right)} \:dx$$

Comment: @Travis - Thanks for the edit too :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are examples of [Borwein integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral). See:

> Borwein, D.; Borwein, J.M., ["Some Remarkable Properties of $\operatorname{Sinc}$ and Related Integrals"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1011497229317), *Ramanujan J.* **5** (2001), 73-89.

John Baez' *Azimuth* blog has an illuminating [post discussing these integrals](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2018/09/20/patterns-that-eventually-fail/), and [Greg Egan](https://plus.google.com/u/0/113086553300459368002/posts/HSFLPd8bm46) gave an intuitive explanation in terms of Fourier transforms for the pattern-breaking phenomenon often mentioned when these integrals come up.

Comment: Thanks @Travis!

Comment: Cheers!$\!\!\!$